# Any history to the current flag used by ISIL?

Tags: islam, middle-east, contemporary-history, flags

I know the current flag used by the Islamic State of Iraq and the Levant (ISIL) is black with white letters stating: "There is no God but Allah" and in the middle of a white circle in black letters the words: "Allah Messenger and Mohammad"... The handwriting reminds me of the style of seal which was pretended to be used by the Prophet Mohammad!

On the other hand Islam is often related to the color green!

[image: ISIL flag]
<sup>[Yascine](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User_talk:Yascine) - [Public Domain](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:AQMI_Flag.svg)</sup>

Has this flag ever been used by any Muslim groups before?

Does it have any proven historical background?

Comment: It's a variant of a common jihadist design that could be traced through Al-Qæda and the Taliban to Pashtun traditions. They are ultimately inspired by the Black Standard of Muhammad.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The flag is known as the [Black Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Standard) of Muhammad. There are many variants of the flag, and as far as I can tell the variant used by ISIS is original, but other variants have been used by many groups before.

The flag can either be a pure black flag, or it may have the [Shahada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shahada) ("There is no god but Allah. Muhammad is the messenger of Allah.") printed on it in white.

- A pure black flag was used by the Abassid Caliphate from the 8th century through the 16th, the Hotaki Empire in the 18th century, and Afghanistan in the late 19th century.

[image: Black Standard]
<sup>[PaD](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:PaD) - [Public Domain](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_Afghanistan_%281880%E2%80%931901%29.svg)</sup>

- An inverted Black Standard is used by the Taliban.

[image: Taliban flag]
<sup>[Lexicon](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Lexicon) - [Public Domain](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_Taliban.svg)</sup>

- Several different variants have been used by modern Islamist and jihadist groups, including al-Qaeda, al-Shabaab, and the Islamic Courts Union.

[image: al-Qaeda flag]
<sup>[Lexicon](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Lexicon) - [Public Domain](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_Jihad.svg)</sup>

- And a variant of the flag is used by ISIL.

[image: ISIL flag]
<sup>[Yascine](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User_talk:Yascine) - [Public Domain](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:AQMI_Flag.svg)</sup>

Comment: Good job i thought as it is an Islamic flag they would use green color as in most modern flags green seems to refer to Islam!

Comment: Do all three flags have the same text written on them?  The writing on the two in the middle is similar enough I assume it's only differing stylistically; but text on the ISIL flag looks very different to my non-Arabic-reading eyes.

Comment: @DanNeely I don't read Arabic either, but I believe it is the same text, just highly stylized.

Comment: The white flag is still used by the taliban: http://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/624/cpsprodpb/52EE/production/_85803212_9a380dbf-a66a-4aa3-916c-9835b2f50128.jpg is a picture from a few days ago when the Taliban took over Kunduz

Comment: @SJuan76 it seemed not to be a satisfactory answer therefore i waited a few days if there are other interpretations. As the so called black standard of Mohammad was unknown to me!

Comment: @DanNeely No the ISIL Flag is a bit different the others differ in the caligraphy and they add the statement Mohammad is the Messenger of God (Allah) while the ISIL is adding a grammatical incorrect sentence or better 3 words (top down) Allah Messenger Mohammad but -to be 100% correct- if you read them bottom-up they will build the statement of the others!

Comment: @DanNeely Different writing scripts. The one in Alqaeda flag is [Thuluth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thuluth) or [Muhaqaq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhaqqaq), not sure. The one in ISIS flag seems to be some variant of [Kufic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kufic).

Comment: @DanNeely And yes they both have same text written on them. The first flag is just simple _"La ilaha Il Allah Muhammad ur Rasool Allah"_ which is basically Muslim creed meaning, _"there is no God but God and Muhammad is prophet of the God"_. ISIS added [Seal of Muhammad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seal_of_Muhammad) to their flag which reads _"Muhammad, Rasool Allah"_, meaning Muhammad Prophet of God. The top caption on that one reads _"La ilaha il Allah"_ which means _"There is no God but God"_

Comment: @Medi1Saif There was no Standard flag of Muslims in history, they primarily used flags simply to distinguish themselves from the enemy so thats why we rarely see any proper Muslim historical state flag or dynasty shields. The black and white flag thing goes back to Rashidun Caliphate IIRC, Where the white flag represented the civil Government or the Caliphate while the Black flag was reserved for the Armies of Caliphate.

Comment: The reason why terrorist organization such as ISIS and Alqaeda associate themselves with the Black flag is a Hadith that _the advent of the Mahdi would be signaled by Black Standards proceeding from Khorasan(Modern day Afghanistan and North West Pakistan) and that it will be the flag of the army that will fight the Anti-Christ._ So they want to present themselves as some prophecized heroes to attract naive young men and women.

Comment: @Medi1Saif It's not grammatically incorrect. It's as it is supposed to be. Modeled after seal of Muhammad.